# Does my 2 months stay in US on B1 visa can cause any problem in L1 approval?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I work in IT with a US product company. I recently in January went to US on B1 visa. My stay lasted for 2 months because of many meetings and training. My company is applying for my L1 visa now. People are telling me that my chances of getting L1 is less because I have to convince the visa officer that I did not work during my 2 months stay on B1. I don't know how to prepare for this scenario. Please guide me if my 2 months stay is really going to cause any problem in getting L1 visa approved.

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to guide you about. It might not even come up. If it comes up, tell them the activities you took part in. Typically meetings and training do not count as work. Two months training is not unheard of unless your company is known to abuse visas that's where you will have a problem. If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie it might be more precise to say that meetings and training count as permissible activities for a business visitor. Of course it's *work,* but that doesn't mean that it's forbidden.  When speaking with US officials, though, it is of course a good idea to avoid the term "work" as much as is practical, to avoid attracting unnecessary scrutiny.